# How to configure Jenkins to see Reports correctly?

Tags: jenkins

How to configure Jenkins to see Reports correctly?

Now these reports looks like this:

[Something is wrong with the Maven Site and other reports on Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld9Dj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to VirtualHost file fixed my problem:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Feature-Policy
    Header set Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'"
    # Referrer-Policy
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    # Content-Security-Policy   
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://jenkins.i4ware.fi; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://jenkins.i4ware.fi;"
    # X-XSS-Protection
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```